# Angular dynamically inserted directive

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I build an app based on angular + [ng-ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) + [ng-googleCharts](http://bouil.github.io/angular-google-chart/#/fat)

I want display google charts data table containing a ui.bootstrap popover in certain cell. I populate rows of table with data from database.

I fetch data with angular [$resource service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) and then parse data with function, which also create html markup for ui.bootstrap popover with popover angular directive. But this popover don't work.

I suggest, that this is because data inserted to table needs to be recompiled by Angular. I searched web and found solutions to this with angular $compile service.

I found custom directive, called `angular-html-bind`, that recompile content of that directive element after each change of binded model, so one can dynamically bind other angular directive to view, but I don't know, how to use modus operandi from `angular-html-bind` in my data table.

I created plunker that describes my effort. Sadly, the `angular-html-bind` directive does not work in that plunker and I don't know why, but that Plunker contains all necessary modules.

## [Plunker HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/vUNaQGTS8CNVsk6MfTNu?p=preview)

Can YOU see any way to my desired goal (that is insert tooltip/popover inside data table cell).

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic popover is not working because the directive google-chart has isolated scope, so I don't think this line is being correctly evaluated.

```
{v: $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.popover)}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, that `$sce.trustAsHtml` has anything to do with that problem. I tried use `$sce` service as solution to my problem, but it neither work with it, as without it. AFAIK, `$sce` only prevent escaping, so if button is rendered as HTML button inside table, that value is not escaped. I need to parse that HTML code with Angular and I'm not sure, that proper `$sce` implementation will help that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I backed up to obvious solution - don't use Google chart data table, but create classic bootstrap style HTML table and populate it with angular expressions.

I tried experimenting with google-chart, but anyway, it dont followed my mantra: **KISS** ("Keep It Sweet & Simple" - this time probably in form "Keep It Simple, Stupid!" :)